# Resolving a hierarchy of classes and interfaces with Unity

Tags: c#, unity-container

*(Writing from memory)*

Trying to do the **I** in SOL**I**D. Given

```
public interface ISettingsReader
{
}

public interface ISettingsWriter : ISettingsReader
{
}

public class SettingsManager : ISettingsWriter
{
}

myContainer.RegisterType<ISettingsWriter, SettingsManager>();
```

why is the following complaining that the `ISettingsReader` cannot resolved:

```
public HomeController(ISettingsReader settingsReader)
{
}
```

I would assume that because I have registered `SettingsManager` to be my `ISettingsWriter`, and `ISettingsWriter` inherits `ISettingsReader`, Unity would be smart enough to figure out that `SettingsManager` is also `ISettingsReader`?

Why do I have to do explicitly:

```
myContainer.RegisterType<ISettingsReader, SettingsManager>();
myContainer.RegisterType<ISettingsWriter, SettingsManager>();
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason you need the explicit registration for both base types is that Unity needs to know specifically what you want back when you resolve an ISettingsReader. The case you're looking for is an implied conversion between interfaces, which Unity does not support.

As an example of why implicit conversions could be problematic, there could be any number of different implementations of the interface:

```
public class SettingsContainer : ISettingsReader { ... }
public class SettingsThing2 : ISettingsReader { ... }
```

You could potentially set up your registrations so that an `IEnumerable<ISettingsReader>` (or some other collection type) automatically resolves to all `ISettingsReader` implementations that are registered. Or, you could want just a single `ISettingsReader`, and Unity wouldn't know which one to give you. I'm not saying this is good design, but it is possible given the constraints of the C# language.

Unity needs to know explicitly which ISettingsReader implementation you want when you try to resolve it. It won't try to do a cast between interfaces for you.

Comment: Of course it should be smart enough to figure out that SettingsManager is ISettingsWriter! That's what I have registered. Yes, there could be many implementations for ISettingsReader. But I have registered only one - indirectly. If I would have registered a second, explicitly, then I would expect it to be the one resolved. If I have a chain of a hundred interfaces with a single implementation, would I need to register each one of them, so that I can use them as DI? This doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @HristoYankov Sorry, that part of the answer is totally unclear, I'll revise it. Though I think your response highlights that if you haven't registered something, how is it supposed to know there is a type implementation? As far as I know, Unity is a container with direct type mappings that doesn't do implicit conversions - it looks like you're looking for something that it just doesn't support.

Comment: But the thing is, it IS registered. `B:C', `A:B` -> `A:C`. `if (A is C) { }` would yield `true`. I am sure Unity can go through its registered implementations and look at least for the first one that implements `C`, no? But you could be right, maybe Unity simply doesn't support such deep resolution.

Comment: @HristoYankov I kind of figured that's what you were getting at with the question, and I think it's a really good point. I can't point to an exact reason why the designers chose not to do this check, but I think (my opinion here) it gives you more flexibility when you have to explicitly register each interface to each implementation. Otherwise you could be relying on the order of dependency registration, which is **not** a good scenario to be in because it can lead to very subtle bugs.